# I keep getting a runaway error in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Can somebody find the error in the code? It gives me a runaway error message every time I compile it followed by an emergency stop.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=sf,labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    ymode=normal,
    enable tick line clipping=false,
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend image post style={mark options={scale=1}},
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.9)},draw=none,
        legend style={row sep=1pt},
        legend style={column sep=3pt}},
    legend cell align={left},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\dot{\epsilon}_n$} [{\myfont s$^{-1}$}]},
    xmin=0.05,xmax=2000,
    xtick={0.1,1,10,100,1000},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    minor x tick num=9,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$E$} [{\myfont GPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=5,
    ytick={0,1,...,5},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]
    \addplot [black,only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.5,fill=white}]
         table [x=x, y=y, y error=ey] {
        x       y       ey
        0.1     89.4    5.9
        1       88.16   3.75
        10      79.43   2.61
        100     84.39   5.26
        1000    86.18   7.19
    };
    \addlegendentry{\myfont machine direction}

    \addplot [black,only marks,mark=square*,mark options={scale=1.5,thick,fill=white] table [x=x, y=y, y error=ey] {
        x       y       ey
        0.1     101.72  12.04
        1       114.03  6.45
        10      82.07   0.6
        100     103.66  8.56
        1000    91.28   7.61
    };
    \addlegendentry{\myfont transverse direction}

    \addplot [black,dashed,semithick] table [x=x, y=y] {
        x       y
        0.05    2.1
        2000    2.1
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is

```
Runaway argument?
black,only marks,mark=square*,mark options={scale=1.5,thick,fill=whit\ETC.
```

and searching for that text you find

```
   \addplot [black,only marks,mark=square*,mark options={scale=1.5,thick,fill=white]
```

which is missing `}`

```
   \addplot [black,only marks,mark=square*,mark options={scale=1.5,thick,fill=white}]
```

runs without error.